# Получить элемент по классу и убрать все классы у него

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу получить по классу элементы и очистить их классы (этот же).
Через итерацию, и такая возникла интересная проблема:
[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/temukster/x962c43t/14/)

По клику на любую кнопку он по сути должен удалять со всех элементов классы, но делает это через одного и вообще непонятно как, только после 3ех нажатий очищаются все.

Пробовал:

`function viewDivMag(number) { [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('chain-shop-adresses'), function(item) {  item.className = 'none'; });`

ничего не поменялось.

В чем проблема не пойму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В чем проблема не пойму

Проблема в том, что `getElementsByClassName` возвращает "живую" (live) коллекцию. При изменении `item.className = 'none';` в коллекции становится меньше элементов.

Используйте `document.querySelectorAll` или преобразуйте результат `document.getElementsByClassName` в массив

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('chain-shop-adresses')].forEach(...
```